# CSS two divs side by side

Tags: html, css

I need two divs side by side with the one on the right always stretched to 100%. The one on the left is not always going to be there and contains an image of 128px width & height. Inside the div on the right is a table that is 100% width. Can this be done? Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I'm confused.  How can you have two divs side by side if one of the divs is 100% wide?

Comment: Believe he means 100% of the remaining space.

Comment: I've tried float left position relative I just can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XF8rA/5/) that (I think) solves your problem. Next time some code would be helpful so we have a place to start.

The trick is to use absolute positioning in the `div` on the right side to make it "stretch." Note that the parent cannot have static positioning.

EDIT: If the image is not always there, you might need some logic when using this technique. Remove/add a class in JavaScript or something to make `.child2` have `left: 0px;`. Not sure what technologies you're using.

EDIT2: [Here is a link](http://devign.me/css-stretch-a-box-to-its-parent-bounds/) to an article that discusses the technique, as well as other situations where it's useful.

Comment: Its not quite what i wanted the left div isn't always visible so the right is always going to be 128px from the left

Comment: I discussed this briefly in the answer. You need logic, which means you need a programming language -- JS, PHP, JSP, whatever -- to make `.child2` have `left: 0px;` when the image isn't present.